# For next loop for date value

Tags: vb.net

How to fix following code?

```
Dim xx As Date = New DateTime(2016, 1, 1)
Dim yy As Date = New DateTime(2016, 12, 31)
For ii = xx To yy
    MsgBox(ii)
Next ii
```

This is the error:

[image]

Comment: Try to count the days between the two dates and run the loop accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `While` loop:

```
While xx <= yy  
    MsgBox(xx)
    xx = xx.AddDays(1)  
End While
```

Or `Enumerable.Range`:

```
Dim days = Enumerable.Range(0, Convert.ToInt32((yy-xx).TotalDays))
    .Select(Function(i) xx.AddDays(i))
For Each DateTime day in days
   MsgBox(day)
Next day
```

(It seems complicated, but it's good to start thinking in terms of describing data as opposed to building loops).

Or a `For` loop:

```
Dim count = Convert.ToInt32((yy-xx).TotalDays)
For i As Integer To Count
    MsgBox(xx.AddDays(i))
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message suggest, you can't increment a Date by adding 1 to it. Assuming that what you intend to do is to add one day, you can use the `AddDays` method.

```
    Dim xx As Date = New DateTime(2016, 12, 29)
    Dim yy As Date = New DateTime(2016, 12, 31)
    Dim ii As Date = xx
    Do Until ii > yy
        MessageBox.Show(ii.ToShortDateString)
        ii = ii.AddDays(1)
    Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim xx As Date = New DateTime(2016, 1, 1)
Dim yy As Date = New DateTime(2016, 12, 31)

Dim intNumDays As Integer = CInt(Math.Ceiling((yy - xx).TotalDays))
For ii As Integer = 0 To intNumDays - 1
  MsgBox(xx.AddDays(ii))
Next ii
```